# Trying to get varying numbers of values from garbled XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column 'rawresponse' in a table with very messy xml output. I'm trying to pull out values from the output where the values always have the same text string ahead of them, but the values can occur multiple times.

For example, say I want to get the value for strengthValue, I might have one record where the 'rawresponse' column would read:

> {"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ","text":"P00000000022805"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}

Then another might read:

> {"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"1.46","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"strength":{"strengthValue":"245.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0"}

So in the first example, strengthvalue occurs once, and the value has two digits before the decimal and one after. In the second, it occurs four times (with different in between each one - it's totally nonstandard), and the number of digits before and after the decimal are all different.

I tried to solve this with another solution I found on here using patindex and substring but couldn't get it to work.

Really what I'd like for output (CTE or whatever as ultimately I need to do different things like get max values, or count the number of times certain values occur) would be the RecordID (another column), and each value for strengthValue for that recordID, eg

```
RecordID    Value
2-AAf-9     22.4
23-T-00     1.4
23-T-00     80.0
23-T-00     146.98
23-T-00     22.001
```

Suggestions?

Comment: 17.1 - are you the person who asked about JSON and then deleted their comment? The data explicitly references XML later in each cell, so not sure it is JSON. EDIT: Though looking at a comparison it does look more like JSON.

Comment: I tried an example of JSON_VALUE and my SSMS is telling me it's "not a recognized built-in function name".

Answer (score 0):

If open to a TVF

Tired of extracting strings (left,right,charindex,etc), I modified a parse/split function to accept two non-like delimerers.  In your case `'strengthValue":"'` and `'"'`

Not exactly sure how your desired results sync-up the the sample data.

**Example or see it on [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cb4f07ddfed422e626c451c7c3d9cc14)**

```
Declare @YourTable table (RecordID varchar(50),rawresponse varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('2-AAf-9','{"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ","text":"P00000000022805"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}')
,('23-T-00','{"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"1.46","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"strength":{"strengthValue":"245.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0"}')

Select A.RecordID
      ,Value = try_convert(decimal(10,2),B.RetVal)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](rawresponse,'strengthValue":"','"') B
 Where try_convert(money,B.RetVal) is not null
```

**Returns**

```
RecordID    Value
2-AAf-9     80.00
23-T-00     80.00
23-T-00     1.46
23-T-00     245.00
23-T-00     80.00
```

**The TVF if interested.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

**BTW** - I was the one who deleted the first comment regarding JSON and not XML

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (recordID VARCHAR(20), rawresponse VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @yourTable(recordID, rawresponse)
VALUES
('2-AAf-9','{"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ","text":"P00000000022805"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}'),
('23-T-00','{"header":{"to":{"qualifier":"ZZZ"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"1.46","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"strength":{"strengthValue":"245.0","strengthForm":{"code":"package"}}},"quantity":{"value":"3.0"}"strength":{"strengthValue":"80.0"}');

-- solution
SELECT 
  t.recordID, 
  strengthValue = SUBSTRING(string.part,1,CHARINDEX('"', string.part)-1)
FROM @yourTable t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('"strengthValue":"')) f(searchTxt)
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8k(t.rawresponse, LEN(f.searchTxt)) ng
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(t.rawresponse, ng.position+LEN(f.searchTxt),30))) string(part)
WHERE ng.token = f.searchTxt;
```

**Results:**

```
recordID             strengthValue
-------------------- ------------------------------
2-AAf-9              80.0
23-T-00              80.0
23-T-00              1.46
23-T-00              245.0
23-T-00              80.0
```